# Как удалить картинки из предварительного просмотра js

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Код JS**
Предварительный просмотр
Подскажите как сделать удаление картинки из предварительного просмотра (например при нажатии на крестик справа на фотографии)

```
function myFunc(input) {

        var files = input.files || input.currentTarget.files;

        var reader = [];
        var images = document.getElementById('images');
        var name;
        for (var i in files) {
            if (files.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                name = 'file' + i;

                reader[i] = new FileReader();
                reader[i].readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);

                images.innerHTML += '<img class="thumb" id="'+ name +'" src="" />';

                (function (name) {
                    reader[i].onload = function (e) {
                        console.log(document.getElementById(name));
                        document.getElementById(name).src = e.target.result;
                    };
                })(name);


                console.log(files[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: дак `files` это массив, удали из него элемент нужный, типа `delete files[1]`

Comment: а на кнопку как повесить удаление ? чтобы каждую картинку можно было удалить

Comment: на кнопку onclick = pop() или shift()

Comment: я ошибся, `files` это объект, причем с приватными свойствами)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, а другой вариант есть тогда ? Я думаю можно по id удалять

Comment: @Элиот удалить блок, это фигня, но файл будет загружен на сервер все равно, сейчас попробую

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, на сервере я удаляю фото через php. Я вот думаю пользователь когда будет загружать фото, сразу все нужные фото не выберет и будет выбирать их по папкам, в итоге может случайно добавить что то не нужное а потом и вовсе передумает. А тут пока фото не загружено на сервер хотелось бы реализовать удаление.

Comment: @Элиот ну я понял, только ты предложил удалить сам блок с картинкой, блок то удалится, а вот сам файл останется в поле, как выбранный и будет ожидать загрузки

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, а вот этот момент действительно я упустил :(

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, с php с перезагрузкой.

Comment: @Элиот я не вижу решение этой проблемы) Вот если ajax ом грузить, то там можно блокировать загрузку, т.к. файлы будут загружаться по одному. ЛИБО отправлять вместе с файлами ещё массив по длине равный количеству выбранных файлов, а там типа проставлять true, false // можно или нельзя грузить, а на сервере проверяешь, если флаг `false` то перемещаешь файл в папку на сервере, да и все. Последний вариант пришел в голову когда писал этот коммент)

Comment: @Элиот это только вечером, если останутся силы, тут доступа к чату нет